# Remove fields of a HyperlinkedModelSerializer's ForeignKey based on the base request parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At the moment i have:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Player

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.is_full = self.context['request'].query_params.get('full', False)

        if not self.is_full:
            base_fields = ['nation', 'club', 'slug', 'common_name', 'image', 'position', 'quality', 'overall_rating',
                           'card_att_1', 'card_att_2', 'card_att_3', 'card_att_4', 'card_att_5', 'card_att_6']

            for field in self.fields:
                if field not in base_fields:
                    self.fields.pop(field)

        self.fields['nation'] = NationSerializer(is_full=self.is_full)
        self.fields['league'] = LeagueSerializer(is_full=self.is_full)
        self.fields['club'] = ClubSerializer(is_full=self.is_full)
```

Which works fine, but the `ClubSerializer` has

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    league = LeagueSerializer()
```

and i want that `LeagueSerializer` to have the fields based on the value of the requests query params. Would it just be a case of not passing it as a kwarg and doing the `self.is_full = self.context['request'].query_params.get('full', False)` check on every Serializer individually?

Answer (score 1):

I put that check on every serializer so even if I am not manually constructing the serializer (for example in `ViewSet`s), the logic works.

Comment: Yea i think i realized after posting this i had a bit of a rubber duck moment, thanks :)

Comment: Never mind i just realised, the ForeignKeys (`league = LeagueSerializer()`) don't have `self.context['request']` to be able to do the check.

Comment: Why not? Every serializer would get the `request` as part of the context. Just put a constructor like this - `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` and make sure you call `super` and you will get `context` as `context = kwargs.get('context', None)` and the `context` would have `request`. `request = kwargs['context']['request']`

Comment: This issue seems to reflect the problem i'm having: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2555